# Using loops to calculate the values of an equation with 2 parameters

Tags: python, numpy

I have this equation `v = (a * (e((b) - 1000))/400)`

`b` is a list of values = `1300, 2100, 2900, 3200, 3800, 4000, 4100, 4200, 4900, 5600`

`a` is all values in the `range(10)`

e is exponential

for the value `a= 0`, the value of `b=1300` is incorporated in the equation.

For the value `a=1` the value `b = 2100` is incorporated and so on.

However, my code is just producing invalid numbers. I'm not sure how to make sure the equation loops through the correct values of b with the corresponding a values. Any help would be appreciated.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
def v(a, b):
    v = ((a) * (np.exp(b) - 1000) / 400)
    b = [1300, 2100, 2900, 3200, 3800, 4000, 4100, 4200, 4900, 5600]
    for a in range(10):
        return ((a) * (np.exp(b) - 1000) / 400)
```

Tried creating a function and for loop to loop through values of `a in range(10)`. But do not know how to incorporate corresponding b values.

Comment: Check out the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function. Also, remove the line `v = ((a) * (np.exp(b) - 1000) / 400)` from your function definition.

Comment: What do you expect `exp(1300)` (or any other values in `b`) to do? That is a HUGE number, and too big for `float`s

Comment: Your equation is actually `a * np.exp(b - 1000) / 400`

Answer (score 1):

You can define `a` as a numpy array and use NumPy's built-in vector maths, e.g.,

```py
import numpy as np
import math
def v():
    a = np.arange(10)  # an array containing 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 
    b = [1300, 2100, 2900, 3200, 3800, 4000, 4100, 4200, 4900, 5600]
    return a * np.exp(b - 1000) / 400
```

This will return a 1D NumPy array with 10 values. Or you can pass the length of `a` and the `b` values into the function, e.g.,:

```py
n = 10
b = [1300, 2100, 2900, 3200, 3800, 4000, 4100, 4200, 4900, 5600]

def v(n, b):
    a = np.arange(n)  # an array containing 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 
    
    return a * np.exp(b - 1000) / 400

# call this with, e.g.,
x = v(n, b)
```

Note: many of your values of `b` will return `inf` when doing `e**(b-1000)` as they are large!

Comment: You should do `a = np.array(a)` instead of redefining it in the function. Not sure why OP's function takes `b` since it redefines that anyway

Comment: Also, technically since you know the size of `b`, you can infer `n` without requiring an additional input. `a = np.arange(len(b))`

Comment: Why are you doing `np.exp(b - 1000)` instead of `np.exp(b) - 1000`?

Comment: It was edited by @PranavHosangadi under the strong assumption that the OP actually meant e^(b - 1000).

Comment: @MattPitkin it isn't an assumption. OP shows their equation in the first line of their question, and after resolving the mess of parentheses, it becomes `a * exp(b - 1000) / 400`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that you can use to calculate the values of `v` for a given value of `a` and a list of values for `b`:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def v(a, b_values):
    results = []
    for b in b_values:
        result = ((a) * (np.exp(b) - 1000) / 400)
        results.append(result)
    return results

b_values = [1300, 2100, 2900, 3200, 3800, 4000, 4100, 4200, 4900, 5600]
v_values = v(10, b_values)
print(v_values)
```

This code defines a function `v` that takes two parameters: `a` and a list of values for `b`. It then uses a loop to iterate over the values in the list for `b`, and calculates the value of `v` for each value of `b` using the input value of `a`. The results are stored in a list, which is returned by the function.

Comment: You address the redefining of `b`, but then you go on to ignore the input `a`. Also, your function calculates the equation for each `a` and `b` in the _product_ of the two collections. OP wants it calculated for the _zip_ of the two

Comment: Also, see [formatting help](/help/formatting). You can show inline code by surrounding it in backticks (e.g. \`a\` is rendered as `a`) instead of bolding it